# How to extract a string from a dictionary in an array into a different array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

hello I have a `NSMutableArray iconlocarr`. I also have another array containing dictionary data called `xmlnodes` which looks like this:

```
{
    nodeChildArray = (
        {
            nodeContent = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png";
        }
    );
    nodeName = weatherIconUrl;
}
```

I am trying to add the `nodeContent` data (icon url) into my `iconlocarr` array:

```
[iconlocarr addObject:[[[xmlnodes objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"]];
```

The problem I have is that the above code adds the following data:

```
(
    {
        nodeContent = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png";
    }
)
```

As well the data I actually want

```
"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
```

How do I just add the nodeContents data and not the rest? The intention is to pass the data to a NSURL

Comment: The word “data” means something specific in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch: An NSData object (or the equivalent element in a plist). You should not call anything else, including strings or dictionaries or arrays, “data”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
iconlocarr addObject:[[[[xmlnodes objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]];
```

which consider object "nodeChildArray" as an array, then extract index 0 and then the returned dictionary will contain the "nodeContent".

Comment: This returns the same result as my code am I missing something? the output consists of a list of all the nodes then a list of all the content. also I believe the above is missing a square bracket at the front?

Comment: can you send the NSLog of "xmlnodes"? NSLog(@"%@",xmlnodes)

Comment: Here is some of the log 
{
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png";
            }
        );
        nodeName = weatherIconUrl;
    },
        {
        nodeChildArray =         (
                        {
                nodeContent = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png";
            }
        );
        nodeName = weatherIconUrl;
    },

Comment: from this log it seems that you have an array (xlmnodes); each element of the array is a dictionary, with two keys: nodeChildArray and nodeName. nodeChildArray key contains an array, each element of the array is a dictionary made of one key, "nodeContent". So my suggestion seems correct and I don't understand why you say it gives the same result of yours, which is different. What can you do in such case is to save this array in a property list using NSArray's writeToFile: and then explore this plist using the property list editor, just in case we missed something in this chain.

Comment: Many thanks for this, It was an error on my part! its all working now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's what it's adding? From your code, I would expect it to add an array containing the `nodeContent` string, e.g.

```
(
    @"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png;
)
```

The problem here is you're trying to extract a single value from an array (your `nodeChildArray` value) and you haven't defined exactly how you want to do that. Do you want the first item in the array? The last? A random item? You should figure that out. In any case, you can use

```
NSArray *ary = [[xmlnodes objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"];
```

to get the `nodeChildArray` value and then determine how exactly you want to pick which value inside it to extract the contents from.

Comment: Many thanks, Ok I should have been more specific I have 5 weather icons one for each day of the week, I want to return just the http:// data contained within the nodeContent field within each nodeChild array and not anything else. The above is in a for loop  Surely I should be able to target this field in each Objectindexed? ie grab the data for each day ather than split the process in two? there is only one nodeContent for each nodechildarray in the index.

Answer (score 0):

KVC should handle this easily:

```
for (id nodeContents in [xmlnodes valueForKeyPath:@"nodeChildArray.nodeContent"])
    [iconlocarr addObjectsFromArray:nodeContents];
```

Comment: Thanks though I get the data in brackets (
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
)
which is one of the issues I was trying to avoid as it needs to be suitable for a NSURL. If I run NSString *url = [[[[xmlnodes objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"]; in a loop and NSLOG the output i get exactly what I want but i need the contents in an array.